# @ManagedProperty initialization

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to store the selected value of the first attribute managedabean "refCont" in a second attribute of the managed bean and then I'll post. but the value will show that after the second selection knowing that the value displayed is the one selected for the first time. I do not know what's sake

.xhtml

```
<h:outputText value="* Contact" /> 
<h:selectOneMenu   id="contact" value="#{reclamationMB.refCont}"  onchange="lazyload()">
    <c:set value="#{reclamationMB.refCont}" target="#{contactMB}" property="refContt" />
    <f:ajax  listener="#{contactMB.affichReclContact}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One"  noSelectionOption="true" itemValue="---" /> 
    <f:selectItems value="#{contactMB.contactsClient}" noSelectionValue="" var="contact" itemValue="#{contact.refCont}" itemLabel="#{contact.nomCont}" />
    <f:selectItems itemLabel="Autre" itemValue=""></f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

first ManagedBean:

```
 @RequestScoped
    public class ReclamationMB extends AbstractMB implements Serializable {
        private int refCont;//ref contact recuperé pour la creation de la  reclamation 
        .....
//getter and setter
```

Second Mnaged bean

```
 @RequestScoped 
    public class ContactMB extends AbstractMB implements Serializable {
    @ManagedProperty("#{reclamationMB.refCont}")
            private int refContt;
            .....
    //getter an setter
    public void affichReclContact(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
            contact=service.AffichContact(refContt);
            setContact(contact);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JSTL's `<c:set>` is a view build time *tag handler*, and not a view render time *UI component*, so your problem is a classical one: when you expect it to set the value, it is no longer there in the component tree. Moreover, it has run when there was no `<h:selectOneMenu>` tag at all.

Of course, if `<h:selectOneMenu>` implemented `ActionSource`, just like `<h:commandButton>`, you could have nested JSF `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` for the reason of setting the bean property with the needed values, as in `<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{contactMB.refContt}" value="#{reclamationMB.refCont}">`. But you can't do that.

Basically you can do two things:

1. Use PrimeFaces `<p:remoteCommand>` tag, which can hold the abovementioned action listener to set the needed value, and call it in `onchange` method. There are a bunch of such examples here on Stack Overflow and in excellent PrimeFaces' documentation.
2. Make use of bean injection, instead of just bean property injection. In the former case, the expression `reclamationMB.getRefCont()` will always yield the right result in the holder bean, provided that `reclamationMB` is the variable to hold the injected bean by `@ManagedProperty`.

Comment: thanks for your explantion, but i can't do the first because I use already the `<p:remoteCommand>` wich i call it in this <selectOneMenu>, i think i can't call two `<p:remoteCommand>` in the same onchange.
The second :i have an error that the `property="reclamationMB.refCont"` is not found when i use "bean injection" 
`<c:set value="#{reclamationMB.refCont}" target="#{contactMB}" property="reclamationMB.refCont" />`

Comment: Firast of all, you can call several remote functions, but that's not needed and may be too expensive. Still, you can *add/nest `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` to that `<p:remoteCommand>`*.  As to the second, `<c:set>` is run only once, so you *can't use it to solve your problem>. Rather, *inject the whole bean* to do the job: `@ManagedProperty("#{reclamationMB}") private ReclamationMB reclamationMB;` with getters/setters, in which way you don't need anything else, in case the injected bean is initialized *just on time*.

Comment: good, it work, but in the second selection. I inject th whole bean , and i add <p:remoteCommand name="lazyload" update="lazypanel">  
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}" target="#{viewScope.shouldRender}" />  
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{contactMB.reclamationMB}" value="#{reclamationMB}"/>
</p:remoteCommand>